# Adding dependencies between jobs in asynchronous queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery, task-queue

I'm looking for a queue that executes asynchronous tasks (like rabbitMQ), in which new tasks could be added to the queue, and will be executed only after previous tasks (which is dependent on) has finished.

So the API I'm looking for is to give any task inserted into the queue a set of identifiers, and the task won't be executed while there is another task with a matching identifier that wasn't executed yet.

Any possibilities for that?

Comment: You can always write that logic yourself in whatever worker service you use, but if you want it available as a primitive, celery does this with `chord` : http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don’t see how it can help me because the tasks should be added to the queue asynchronously, so I can’t create a chord at any point - whenever a new task should be spawned it has to be queues till the point that all previous depended tasks has finished.

Answer (score -1):

You can create dependencies between tasks by using [celery's work-flows](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html).